# how to use liveview in dreamweaver cs5 and local xampp server

Tags: php, jquery, css, xampp, dreamweaver

Can someone give me some insight on how to work with liveview locally.

The problem I am having now is that liveview works ok with the remoteserver,
but with xampp the css is a little distorted.

I can't come up with an explanation.

Can someone shed some light?

Thanks, Richard

Comment: That's very weird, are you loading all the files correctly? No hidden spaces or something when switching back to localhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your apache configuration. Sometimes mod_rewrite rules can interfere with the way apache serves content on your machine. It's possible that dreamweaver is doing some funky stuff behind the scenes that doesn't jibe well with your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: I think you can have a point there. I don't have a lot experience with local xampp, but for testing layouts I now make the code in one page to avoid this kind off problem. It seems it also has a problem including separated css files from deeper nested folders. I will manage for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I'm too junior to add a comment so I'll have to answer. I've had problems with Live View as well.  I find it easier to view the rendered page in a browser.  My development files are on the local XAMPP testing server so I just save the changes and refresh the browser.  I then know for sure how it works in at least one browser. In the case of Firefox you can add in Firebug and have a great testing tool.

I just noticed you mentioned you are using CS5.  I'm on CS4, but I doubt I would change my approach when I go to CS5.